Siebel It is necessary to select a string according to the condition when loading the applet
I tried to do it through UI PM manifests, everything seems to work out, but the first entry is selected at the end of the script
Used
if(this.ExecuteMethod ("HandleRowSelect", i, false, false)){                                                       console.log("Work " + i +" ");
};
as a result, the console displayed
Work 7
there is also 1 entry selected on the applet

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem was solved by adding a delay
setTimeout(() => {
this.ExecuteMethod("HandleRowSelect", selectRecord, false, false);
}, 1 * 100);
